# Parsing Json in Node.js which holds numbers as its key param

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, jsonparser

My JSON holds numbers in its key param for an example:

`"abc_12345_xyz":"value"`.

I am fetching this *12345* from my property file and framing the key param dynamically, while parsing it. For an example

```
var num=fetching from prop file(12345).
var jsonValue=jsonObj.value[0].abc_+num+_xyz
```

I am not getting the value while performing the above step, is there anyway to frame the key parameter dynamically.

Comment: try this=>          
                           var jsonValue=jsonObj.value[0][`abc_${num}_xyz`]    there is tilda before a & after z

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
jsonObj.value[0]["abc_"+num+"_xyz"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you will have a list in your properties file and want to get the value based on the entry, like using a regex to get any key that have the property content, you can loop through the keys and check if it have the word on the key. See below this example:

```js
var obj = {
  "abc_12345_xyz": "test_value_1",
  "abc_qwert_xyz": "test_value_2"
};

var prop_file = [12345, 'qwert'];

for (var key in obj) {
  if (key.indexOf(prop_file[1]) > -1) {
    console.log(key, obj[key]);
  }
}
```

Or if the key will always having the prefix and suffix static, you can simply:

```
obj["abc_"+ prop_value +"_xyz"];
```